# scp to remote server message.."Hello, I'm freeFTPd 1.0

Tags: scp

I'm trying to scp files from a Linux box to a remote server, but after i put the root password for the server, it gives the message "Hello, I'm freeFTPd 1.0" 
I tried using put command but nothing is happening.. .. Any idea please

Comment: please show exactly what you're typing, and exactly what the response is.

Comment: [root@--]#scp (file name) admin@(remote server ip):/DATA
The authenticity of host '(remote server ip)" cant be established.
RSA key fingerprint is -----
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '(remote server ip)' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@(remote server ip)'s password:
Hello, I'm freeFTPd 1.0

so what we do now?????

Answer (score 2):

An FTP server is (unexpectedly) running on port 22, which is usually used for SSH. Find out the SSH port on the server. Then specify the port `scp` should connect to using the `-P` (uppercase P) command line option.

Answer (score 0):

freeFTPd can also do sftp, but I'm not sure if it can scp.

What you're seeing is most likely the Greeting message file configured on the freeFPTd server.  You can simply remove the Greeting message file.  I'd also advise to try using sftp instead of scp.